# Would Arduino Nano be good for Bluetooth + Sound

Tags: bluetooth, sound

So I've been browsing around for a whole looking for a good microcontroller that's super small. So far the smallest one I found was an Arduino Nano. But before I go buying it, there are some questions I have about it.

1. Is Bluetooth compatible with it and if so where would I get the Bluetooth code?
2. Is there anything smaller than it that's Bluetooth compatible?
3. Would an Arduino Nano (Or the device in the question above) be able to play sounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [Bluetooth boards](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1588) and chips that you can connect to a Nano.

You can play sounds with a Nano. Crudely with PWM and a direct connection, for finely with an external digital-to-analog converter.

But if super-smallness is what you are after, there may be better options.

The [Blue Bean](http://www.makershed.com/products/lightblue-bean-bluetooth-4-0) is a complete  BLE microcontroller on a single board that is smaller than a Nano+board.

If you want even smaller, you could get something like the new Cypress EZ-BLE module...

[image]
http://www.cypress.com/products/ez-ble-module-bluetooth-smart

It is a complete programmable BLE system on a tiny module. It is hard to imagine anything smaller than that!

Comment: Can a blue bean connect to a Windows usb port @bigjosh

Comment: In theory, could this Cypress BLE module be grafted into an existing piece of consumer electronics (I'm thinking portable video games system) and wired up to deliver Bluetooth audio for wireless headphones? Assuming skills, space inside the device, access to appropriate connections for power and audio in...

Comment: @RowanHarley You'd typically use Bluetooth to connect to the blue bean, so you don't need a USB connection.

Comment: @MickWaites If you want to deliver audio over the connection, then you probably want Bluetooth rather than only BLE. Probably the easiest way to stream audio to some bluetooth headphones is to get one of [these](https://www.amazon.com/Bluetooth-Wireless-Stereo-Adapter-Transmitter/dp/B00N1R7W9Q/ref=as_sl_pc_ss_til?tag=joshcom-20&linkCode=w01&linkId=F4H3547YVRPJFATZ&creativeASIN=B00N1R7W9Q) and take it apart to fit into your game system.